# best way to store html in sql using php - display in htmlText in as3

Tags: php, html, mysql, actionscript-3, flash

I am having many issues getting html to display correctly in my using a  dynamic textField in as3. I am having two main issues.

1. Either the `<br>` and `<p>` are not showing he leaves no line breaks or not the correct formatting with no spaces between some words etc...
2. there is an error loading because I have it stored in the database wrong, or I am sending the var to flash wrong so flash can't read it or display it correctly.

I understand there are a few levels of complexity to this that could be found in one or all of these 3 codes.

1. Storing it in the database and using best format.
2. Pulling it from the database and converting it to a string that can be sent to as3.
3. Getting the as3 to display the html correctly.

I am not worried about css styles or any other html. I just want it to display the format correctly with the right line breaks etc...

**One important note.** I am pulling the html from an external page so I don't have control over all the extra html code in this, such as styles etc....

In mySql I am storing the html in a TEXT type as opposed to varchar etc...

**Here is the php code that is storing the html text.**

```
<?
// I am only showing what I believe to be the relevant code. 
//I am mainly concerned about the Content var.

    $content = trim(strip_tags(addslashes($content)));
    // Also tried the line below without the strip tags
    $content = trim(addslashes($content));

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO myDataBase (Content, Title) VALUES ('$content','$t'");
?>
```

**Here the php code that is getting the content from the sql.**

```
<?
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $Content[] =  stripslashes($row['Content']);
}

/// sending to as3
echo "&Content1=$Content[1]";

?>
```

**Here is the as3 code that is displaying the html.** (Not working well)

```
public function popeContent()
        {
    var formatT = new TextFormat( );

    formatT.bold = false;
    formatT.color = 0x454544;
    formatT.font = "TradeGothic";
    formatT.size = 40;
    formatT.leading = 10;
    formatT.font = "Arial";

    theContent.multiline = true;
    theContent.wordWrap = true;
    theContent.htmlText = Content1;     
    theContent.width = 1075;
    theContent.y = 0;
    theContent.x = 0;
    theContent.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;


    theContent.setTextFormat(formatT);

    addChild(theContent);

        }
```

Any help to send me in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: Ehh, you pass the content through `strip_tags()`. That may have something to do with it. Also, there is no reason to use `addslashes()`; use prepared statements instead.

Comment: htmlentities() and on display html_entity_decode() http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Oh I did try it without the strip_tags

Comment: Rakesh, you must have relized this would not work? You deleted your answer. Just wondering. thnaks